# prettifying Java XML output

Tags: java, xml

I have a simple question about Java's XML API and I hope there's a simple answer too:

Lets say that after processing I have the following XML output:

```
<a>
    <b><c>
    <d> <e> some content
        </e>    </d>
    </c>    </b>
</a>
```

The structure is correct but whitespaces are all over the place. The question is that how can I prettify the output so that it looks something like this:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c> 
            <d>
                <e>some content</e>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

Only catch is that I can't use anything but Java 5's own XML API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Transformer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html).[setOutputProperty](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setOutputProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))([OutputKeys](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html).[INDENT](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#INDENT), "yes").

Comment: Thanks, knew it'd be easy, just didn't know where to look.

Comment: Yes, it’s not that well documented. OutputKeys also has a couple of other constants for more nifty stuff. :)

Comment: Don't work for me! The only thing that happens is that each element starts at a new line, but no indents! I have JDK6u14.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior.  My input XML is all one line, no whitespace, and my output XML has every element in a new line, but without indents. _Edit:_ Just saw this somewhere else, and it worked: `Transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");` Of course, you can change the "2" to whatever indent amount you want. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2")
```

This doesnt work for me either. WTF? java version "1.6.0_29"

```
Transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")
```